# TextColor is the same as listviews background what to do?

Tags: android, listview

I have a very simple ListActivity in my application using HoloLight theme. My ListView is being populated but the text is only visible when an item is highlighted. How do I fix this and why does it happen?

**Edit** : To clarify. Rather than fixing this locally in each list view I want to find a global solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several good answers. But, most of them included writing a new adapter which is unnecessary work. The most important thing is that you should have the color desired set in your xml. I wrote a new layout with the source for simple_list_item_2 and added a line to change text color. Tested and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2006-2007 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
-->

<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:mode="twoLine"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</TwoLineListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make your own adapter which can then be used to show the items in the ListView

You can find some more information here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html But I know there are also numerous other sites on the internet that will give a good explanation (Google is your friend)

Comment: I don't see that as a solution as this problem will occur every time I create a list view. I would like to find some place to apply the change so that my list view will always the same colors. Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case, this is indeed not the best option. Except of course, you always use the same adapter. So it is still a possible solution, but maybe not the best

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example custom adapter that loads a custom layout and as long as you use this one in all of the list, they will behave the same way and will look the same, and to make it work you just need to define what you want to display and what type of object are you using.

CUSTOM ADAPTER:

```
public class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private List<Object> YourObjects;

    public YourAdapter(Context context, List<Object> YourObjects, List<String> headings) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view_stories, headings);
        this.context = context;
        this.YourObjects = null != YourObjects ? YourObjects : new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /*Setup the things need it to inflate each row*/
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_stories, parent, false);

        /*Retrieves the views for the heading and title from the layout*/
        TextView heading = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView summary = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.summary);

        heading.setText(YourObjects.get(position).getHeading());
        summary.setText(YourObjects.get(position).getSummary());

        /*Returns the row with the content placed*/
        return rowView;

    }

}
```

CUSTOM LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:background="@color/ligth_blue" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/summary"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Change the color in the layout properties.

```
android:textColor="@color/black"
```

and then you create a resource in your values folder, here is an example of some colors i use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="gray">#909090</color>
    <color name="ligth_blue">#2E9AFE</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the theme handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom ListView. You customize each row in your own way. There a lot of examples of listview just google it. http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429. Also have a look at this link. http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

Comment: I don't see why I should write a custome list view to apply a different text color. In that case I would just write a new item layout.